# Is there a way to make my if statement more efficient with an enum?

Tags: c, string, parsing, enums

I am working on a simple parser which takes a string as input and parses a string to see if the opening and closing parentheses/brackets/braces are correctly placed. One step in this involves me skipping every character that is not a valid token (a parenthesis, bracket, or brace), because at this point I don't care whether the expression inside the parentheses are valid or not–I'm only interested in whether the parentheses are syntactically correct. I wrote an if statement which tells the loop to skip to the next iteration when it encounters anything that's not an opening or closing brace, but the code looks ugly and is repetitive. I was wondering if there was a better way to do it–perhaps with an enum. Directly below is the function in question, (parse), and below that, I've pasted the code for the entire program so far. If you answer or attempt to answer this, thank you for your time.

```
void parse(char *string) {
  for (int i = 0; i < strlen(string); i++) {
    if (string[0] == ')' || string[0] == ']' || string[0] == '}') {
      printf("ParseError: Statement begins with invalid token '%c'", string[0]);
      return;
    }
    if (string[i] != '(' || string[i] != '[' || string[i] != '{' ||
        string[i] != ')' || string[i] != ']' || string[i] != '}') {
      continue;
    }
  }
}
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Node {
  char character;
  struct Node *link;
} * top;

struct Node *getNewNode(char);
void push(char);
void pop(void);
void parse(char *);
void print(void);

int main() {
  top = NULL;
  char string[100];
  char *string_ptr = string;
  printf("Enter an expression to parse: ");
  fgets(string, sizeof(string), stdin);
  parse(string_ptr);
  print();
}

struct Node *getNewNode(char character) {
  struct Node *newNode = (struct Node *)(malloc(sizeof(struct Node)));
  newNode->character = character;
  newNode->link = top;
  return newNode;
}

void push(char character) {
  struct Node *newNode = getNewNode(character);
  top = newNode;
}

void pop(void) {
  struct Node *temp;
  if (top == NULL) {
    printf("Stack is empty!");
    return;
  }
  temp = top;
  top = top->link;
  free(temp);
  temp = NULL;
}

void print(void) {
  struct Node *temp = top;
  while (temp != NULL) {
    printf("%c", temp->character);
    temp = temp->link;
  }
}

void parse(char *string) {
  for (int i = 0; i < strlen(string); i++) {
    if (string[0] == ')' || string[0] == ']' || string[0] == '}') {
      printf("ParseError: Statement begins with invalid token '%c'", string[0]);
      return;
    }
    if (string[i] != '(' || string[i] != '[' || string[i] != '{' ||
        string[i] != ')' || string[i] != ']' || string[i] != '}' ||) {
      continue;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you are looking for a more concise way of writing it, you could do something like `if (strchr(")]}", string[0]) != NULL) { ... }`. But this will be less efficient from the run time point of view.

Comment: don't check `string[0]` within the loop -- once is enough -- and leave the rest to the compiler's optimizer.

Comment: Enums are just syntactic sugar for integer values. You cannot speed up anything using them. For better performance you should: a) not use `strlen` in the loop condition where the function is called in each iteration. b) check `string[0]` for each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Here's a beginner's mistake that you should *never* have in your code:  `for (int i = 0; i < strlen(string); i++)`  This loop is calling `strlen` *every time through*.  That immediately makes the loop itself O(n**2) for no reason. You should call `strlen` *once*, before entering the loop, and save the result in a variable that you use in the loop test, e.g. `for (int i = 0; i < slen; i++)`.

Comment: @TomKarzes A common C idiom: `for (int i = 0; i < strlen(string); i++)` ==> `for (int i = 0; string[i]; i++)`.  No need for prior `strlen(string)` call.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Yes, that's another way to do it, although it does load `string[i]`, which presumably the loop body does as well.  If the compiler has a good optimizer, it should common-sub the array load.  And of course, `strlen` is loading the entire array to find the length.

Answer (score 0):

This *may* be a good use case for a `switch`:

```
void parse( char *string )
{   
  /**
   * Make sure string[0] is valid first
   */
  switch( string[0] )
  {
    case ')':
    case ']':
    case '}':
      fprintf( stderr, "parse error..." );
      return;
      break;
    
    default:
      break;
  }

  /** 
   * Compute the length of the string once rather
   * than every time through the loop.  
   */
  size_t len = strlen( string );

  for ( size_t i = 0; i < len; i ++ )
  {
    /**
     * Is the current character a delimiter?
     */
    switch( string[i] )
    {
      case '(':
      case ')':
      case '[':
      case ']':
      case '{':
      case '}':
          // we'll process the delimiter character following
          // the end of the switch statement
        break;

      default:
        // this is not a delimiter, go back to the beginning of
        // the loop
        continue;
        break;
    }

    // process delimiter character
  }
}
```

but that ***heavily*** depends on how you're going to process other characters once you beef up your parser.  Switches can get ugly and unmaintainable in a hurry.  I've written this such that the switches act only as filters; they simply decide whether to proceed with the current operation or not, there's no processing logic in either one.

Answer (score 0):

There are college courses on parsing theory. We construct software “machines” of various kinds to parse strings, so good solutions for issues like this involve incorporating them into an overall parsing scheme, not solving each one individually.

However, given that, a typical way to handle something like this is to prepare an array with information about the characters:

```
#include <limits.h>

// Define bit flags for character properties.
enum { IsOpener = 1, IsCloser = 2, };

// Initialize array with flags for characters.
static unsigned CharacterProperties[UCHAR_MAX+1] =
{
    ['('] = IsOpener,
    ['['] = IsOpener,
    ['{'] = IsOpener,
    [')'] = IsCloser,
    [']'] = IsCloser,
    ['}'] = IsCloser,
};

…

if (CharacterProperties[string[0]] & IsOpener)
    … // Here string[0] is one of the “open parentheses” type of characters.
```

Note there are some sign issues to watch out for: The subscript to `CharacterProperties` should be nonnegative, so `string` should be `unsigned char *` or you should cast it with `(unsigned char)` in the subscript or you should ensure `char` is unsigned. And, if any of the characters in the initialization could be negative (are not in C’s basic execution character set), they should be cast too.